# Possible to Add ServiceReference (ASMX) to Visual Studio Template (VSIX)?

Tags: c#, silverlight, asmx, vsix

When I add a Service Reference ("`MyWebService.asmx`") to my template, I have two issues.

1. The `References.svcmap` always has things like: `Silverlight_Application_Template.MyWebService.ZrrayOfXElement.datasource`.  I don't think I really want the template name in the file name.  Instead, I would like for them to get renamed to something more like: "`$SafeProjectName$.MyWebService.ZrrayOfXElement.datasource`" where "`SafeProjectName`" is what gets replaced by the name the user enters for the project when they create the template.
2. I get a `PathTooLongException`  when I run the VSIX, because of the file listed above.

Is there a way to get this to work?  I could just tell the users to add a ServiceReference immediately after they create a project using the template, but eliminating an extra step is always nice.

**Thank you for reading and for any/all help/tips/suggestions.  Have a great Wednesday!**